# Video player with motion blur or frame averaging

Tags: filter, video-player

I here would be a good place to ask, I apologize if Im mistaken.

I am looking for a video player that can add motion blur to videos or that can insert an average frame in between two frames.

The reason I think I need this is because some videos appear stuttery on a low response time monitor. If I connect an older monitor to the exact same setup, the problem goes away. I figured it would be a good way to test this theory.

Comment: What you're looking for is a video editor or a video converter.  Would that be a solution to your question too?

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has a motion blur option under Tools > Effects and Filters > Video Effects > Advanced.

As a bonus, it can natively take the URL of some video sites, like YouTube.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for after effects.